# nodejs http client requests are using too much CPU

Tags: node.js, http, xmlhttprequest, axios

I'm testing my app performance.
It is a backend app written in `js` running on `node.js`.
I'm using `axios` lib with default configurations to execute simple `http` GET requests.

Monitoring the infrastructure, I see that when I send ~800 req/sec the `cpu` reach to 100%.
Running the same `http` GET to the same url using `curl` in the same server, I can send ~2700 req/sec and the `cpu` reach to 55%.

I'm using `node` version 8.
Is it something I do wrong with `axios`?
Is there any limitation on the `node` platform?